# Getting lots of unwanted 404 logs in my website

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

From the past few months, i am facing issue of getting 404 errors that caused due to requesting some bad URLs. I have no idea from where these links came from. In website we don't have such links. Few examples are:

There are links like:

www.abc.com/definition/1333/text/javascript

www.abc.com/undefined

www.abc.com/twitter.json

The above are just samples, i am getting 100s of them daily with different keywords.

Had anybody experienced the same issue?

Comment: Looks like links generated in javascript using an undefined variable. With your logging (whether you log it in your application, or just use IIS), enable logging of the referrer and see if you can capture where the bad links are originating from. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754702(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Do you have a common user agent that is getting the 404s for the various enteries? I find that some spiders are major culprits for this one some of my sites.

Comment: Looks like all type of user agent are get logged few are:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11    
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11    
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.152 Safari/535.19    
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)    
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2

Comment: mark-ups seems to be fine, i have re-checked manytimes but no where i found any wrong urls. All seems to be fine. But the 404 urls logged is really weird. Say i have 2 links in the website a) /definition/211/test-case and b) /topic/181/security. I am getting 404 for a page like www.abc.com:80/definition/211/test-case/topic/181/security. This is one type but other format of errors are also there like www.abc.com:80?s=register and www.abc.com:80/signup which are weird!!!. Also one point to note is the port appended with :80 everytime

Answer (score 2):

If there is no way a regular (ie. human) visitor can reach those locations through links on your site you've got nothing to worry about.

There are many crawlers out there who searches the web for exploitable software. These crawlers jump from website to website using URLs they know will tell them if a certain application is running or not.

---

You should however be careful and double check so that you don't have a mark-up error or similar leading your visitors to 404s.

Always blame yourself before you blame someone else. One way to see if it's your fault is to start loggin the `Referer` header (to see what page lead up to the `404`), even though that can be faked easily you'd still be faced with enough facts to rule out one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As per the referrer is concerned, every time it is blank ('').

Comment: mark-ups seems to be fine, i have re-checked manytimes but no where i found any wrong urls. All seems to be fine. But the 404 urls logged is really weird. Say i have 2 links in the website a) /definition/211/test-case and b) /topic/181/security.   I am getting 404 for a page like www.abc.com:80/definition/211/test-case/topic/181/security. This is one type but other format of errors are also there like www.abc.com:80?s=register and www.abc.com:80/signup which are weird!!!. Also one point to note is the port appended with :80 everytime